# Purposefully unevenly space x Axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Lets say I have some data kinda like the mtcars dataset (except the cyl variable is a factor in my case):

```
library(tidyverse)
Data<-mtcars
```

And lets say i want to do a graph kinda like this:

`Data%>%ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(cyl),y=mpg))+geom_boxplot()`

[image]

But lets say I wanted to just kinda stretch the x axis out like this, simply for the visual effect.  And pardon my ms paint skills, it would be one continuous graph with the grid lines stretching the whole way

[image]

Any idea how?  I don't really want to break up the graph like I assume facets would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the factor to numeric positions, you can relatively easily let the x-axis look like it is discrete.

```r
library(tidyverse)

pos <- c(1, 5, 6)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl2 = pos[as.numeric(as.factor(cyl))]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl2, y=mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = as.factor(cyl))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pos,
                     labels = levels(as.factor(mtcars$cyl))) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 1.5, xmax  = 4.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
           fill = "white", colour = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: I think the white rect is not what the OP wanted, although +1 for the effect :D

Comment: Hey I have full trust in OPs paint skills and I assume that is exactly what he wanted :D